# Fedora httpd.conf virtualhost

Tags: apache, fedora, httpd.conf

I trying to move localhost to home folder, but I get an error 403. Here end of httpd.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  DocumentRoot /home/valera5505/sites/localhost
  ServerName localhost
  <Directory /home/valera5505/sites/localhost>
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (I'm not an Apache pro) :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  DocumentRoot /home/valera5505/sites/localhost
  ServerName localhost
  <Directory /home/valera5505/sites/localhost>
    Options FollowSymLinks 
    AllowOverride None 
    Order deny,allow 
    Allow from all 
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And try (I'm still not a professional Linux user ):

```
chmod 755 /home/valera5505
chmod 755 /home/valera5505/sites
chmod 755 /home/valera5505/localhost
```

Comment: Can you tell us what is inside your apache error.log ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you assigned correct privileges ?

## chown apache:apache -R /home/valera5505/sites

## chmod 775 -R /home/valera5505/sites

using -R param is better
also join your user at the apache group

hope you help